# thumbnail image in prestashop 1.6 is not in position

Tags: php, css, prestashop

i have installed prestashop 1.6 in my site at dtopengdistro.com
I have added category thumbnail image. I do not change anything from default page from prestashop.
The thumbnail image at top horizontal menu should be located at the bottom. But, when I added the thumbnail, it located on the right side.
I have tried to configure /mytheme/css/module/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css, but its not work.
try to edit module/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.php is not work too.
So, how can I make the thumbnail of category image located at the bottom like prestashop default page after installation?

Comment: Is this question really a question for StackOverflow? Try the sister site http://superuser.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to previous version of this module (BLOCKTOPMENU). I had the same problem and now it is working fine.

Comment: Ok, at last, i reinstalled my prestashop and do not update any module in prestashop.